# Issue with custom TableViewCells in table display from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm having a weird issue - in my code I am fetching data from the internet in XML format and fill a NSMutableArray (altogether 34 items).

This data should be displayed in a TableView. I created a custom TableViewCell for that. However it always only displays the first 10 items (0-9), then the 11th item will change as you scroll up the table (starting from 11 and changing itself to 12, 13, 14 ...), then it will display the first 10 items again.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [myCurrencies count];
}

    - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *myIdentifier = @"CurrencyDisplayCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurrencyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = tableViewCell;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            self.tableViewCell = nil;
        }

        NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);

        actualRate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myRates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        currencyCode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i) %@",indexPath.row,[myCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        countryFlag.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.gif",[myCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        return cell;
    }
```

However when I just set the textlabel of the standard cell everything is fine and I am displayed 34 table rows with numbers 0 - 33:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
```

Any idea out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your cell initialization is wrong

first of all name all your labels and image views in Interface Builder with tag
for example actualRate - tag 101
currencyCode tag 102
countryFlag tag 103

then

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *myIdentifier = @"CurrencyDisplayCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CurrencyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        }

        NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);

        [((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101]) setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myRates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        [((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102]) setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%i) %@",indexPath.row,[myCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        [((UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:103]) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.gif",[myCurrencies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];

        return cell;
}
```